# f format for string for python in visual studio 2015

Tags: python, visual-studio-2015

> Why visual studio 2015 doesn't recognize "f" format in strings in python?
>   Please guide me.

[image: The error in visual studio 2015]

> By the Way, I have installed python 3.8 but the IDE doesn't recognize it and the default python for visual studio is 2.7

Comment: `f-string`s are implemented from python3.6. You should change the interpreter to python3.8

Comment: @Ch3steR How should I change it ?

Comment: Which Python version are you using?

Comment: python 3.7 64(bit)

Comment: Try updating Visual Studio. Is there any particular you're running 2015?

Comment: @GordonAitchJay No . but it's visual studio 2017 and 2019 are so heavy . I mean like 40 GBs is way too much

Comment: Fair enough 40 GB is a lot! Though, fwiw, my Visual Studio and Microsoft SDKs installation combined is ~9 GB (2017 Community edition).

Comment: @GordonAitchJay I have solved it. thanks buddy:)